# what topological space $X$ has a fundamental group isomorphic to the group of automorphism of the disk in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Since the set of automorphisms of the disk in the complex plane is a group,
we could ask the question of whether there exists a topological space such that the fundamental group of that space is a group isomorphic to the automorphisms of the disk?

Moreover I have a secondary question which might sound dumb: can an automorphism of the disk ($D$ in $\mathbb{C}$) be viewed as a path connecting two points of $D$?
if not is it because an element of Aut($D$) map a point of $D$ to a point of $D$ in a "discontinuous way", like "a jump from one point to another" (because the image of such a map is a singleton) ?

Comment: One example is the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\operatorname{Aut}(D), 1)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space

Comment: I don't find any information about the structure/property of this space and where is it used for ?

Comment: Automorphisms of the disk as what?

Comment: as a map from a compact interval into the disk
an automorphism of the disk is a permutation between points but is the permutation happening in a continuous way or not ?

Comment: (analogically when you move a piece on a chess board either you pull the piece out of the board to move it on another place of it or you slide it all over the board...)